# How to hide the rotating circle on the browser title when twisted server holds the connection?

Tags: html, iframe, twisted

I have made a simple chat using the twisted server. The server holds the connection to send back data. Because of this, there is always a rotating circle on the browser title. I tried calling the server from inside an iframe but it still rotates. How to hide that ?